# Specialize generic function with a type that is itself a generic

Tags: typescript

In general, "specializing" generic functions in Typescript can be implemented by returning functions:

```
export function twice<T>() {
  return (obj: T): [T, T] => {
    return [obj, obj];
  };
}

interface Bar {
  bar: string;
}

const twiceBar = twice<Bar>();
```

Here, `twiceBar` basically is identical to `(obj: Foo) => [obj, obj]`.

Is it possible to specialize a function with a type that is itself a generic?

```
interface Baz<T> {
  baz: T;
}

const twiceBaz = twice<Baz>(); // <--- does not compile
```

Here, I'd like `twiceBaz` to be `<T>(obj: Baz<T>) => [obj, obj]`. How can that be achieved?

Comment: Since twiceBaz is a constant, it can not generic.

Comment: @LongNguyenDuc not true: `const foo = <T>(x: T) => x` is also a const and is generic.

Comment: yes, I'm wrong. Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is `twice<Baz<T>>` while letting `T` remain generic. The function `twiceBaz` is generic over this `T`, by specifying it, your problem will be solved.

```
function twiceBaz<T>() {
  return twice<Baz<T>>();
}
```

You need to specify `twiceBaz` as a function that calls `twice` because that's the only way to get a new `T` generic parameter.

The signature ends up being exactly the one you want and it works:

```
interface Baz<T> {
  baz: T;
}

const twiceBazNumber = twiceBaz<number>();
const numberBaz = {
  baz: 2;
};

console.log(twiceBazNumber(numberBaz)); // [ { baz: 2 }, { baz: 2 } ]
```